# Java proxy server HTTPS request forwarding

Tags: java, sockets, http, https, proxy

I'm currentlty developping a java web server proxy fot http and https request. My server works well for http request but I can't make it for Https request... 
The browser send me a `CONNECT` request but when forwarding it to the target I don't have any data... Can you helping me with that ?

Here my code

```
socket = new Socket(host, 443);

// send connect message to httphost
toServer = socket.getOutputStream();
toServer.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
toServer.flush();

fromServer = socket.getInputStream();
toClient = sock.getOutputStream();
byte[] responseBuffer = new byte[1024];
int j = 0;
while ((j = fromServer.read(responseBuffer)) > 0) {
    toClient.write(responseBuffer, 0, j);
    toClient.flush();
}

toClient.close();
fromServer.close();
```

Comment: It is not clear what you code has to do with the CONNECT method, except that it sends some data around. To read how this method should be processed read [RFC 2817](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2817.txt).

Comment: In fact the browser is requesting a tunnel but i don't know how to forward it to the target.. What do I have to do to the reaiest to get an https proxy server ?

Comment: It's not clear to me what your problem is. After the initial and successful HTTP CONNECT handshake you simply have to pass all data unchanged between client and server in both directions.

Comment: But how to do the handshake? Should it be between the proxy and the target or between client and target? And how do I do it?

Comment: You don't do any handshakes but simply pass the original data. Only if you want to make a proxy with man-in-the-middle capabilities (SSL interception) you have to care about handshakes - but this would be way beyond your question.